# whats the pblm with the following c# code for storing date n time into sql server?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I'm trying to store date and time into sql server, but am getting error.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string d = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        string t = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into transaction values("+label9.Text+",'"+d+"','"+t+"');";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        int x= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Attendance recorded succesfully");   
    }
```

**NOTE**: I gave datatype as varchar for date and time fields in sql server

Comment: Please can you post the error message, and the line of code on which it occurs.

Comment: ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'transaction'. At line 8 in this code...

Comment: post the query that gets into cmd.commandText while debugging

Comment: Using varchar as opposed to the SQL date type is limiting. No localisation support in the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

use     [transaction] instead of transaction

Comment: and also schema for best practices

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string timeString = "11/12/2009 13:30:00.000";
        IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
        DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", culture);
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into transaction values(" + label9.Text + ",'" + dateVal + "');";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Attendance recorded successfully");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string d = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        string t = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into transaction values("+label9.Text+",'"+d+"','"+t+"');";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        int x= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Attendance recorded succesfully");   
    }
```

Secondly you can also try using SQLs' GetDate() Function, to insert the date and time without error.

For only date part, you have:

```
 SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Advantages for date part:

- No varchar<->datetime conversions required
- No need to think about locale

Time Part:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7))
```

I would be happy if someone could help getting TimePart w/o using Convert and Locale.